# MongoTemplate: sum values of keys for documents matching a certain criterion

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, mongotemplate, spring-mongodb

My following mongodb query works as expected

```
db.importedDataItems.aggregate({
    $match: {
        mobile: "1234567890"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 'mobile',
        calls: { $sum: '$calls' }
    }
 })
```

but even after referring to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875668) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25294509) & [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/), its equivalent Java code...

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("mobile").is("1234567890"),
    Aggregation.group("mobile").sum("calls").as("totalCalls"),
    Aggregation.project("totalCalls"));
AggregationResults<Doc> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "yoCollection",
    Doc.class);
Doc doc = results.getMappedResults().get(0);
```

...returns an empty list & throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` though my query returns results on console!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis for the `match()` parameter:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("mobile").is("1234567890")), // <-- missing closing parenthesis
        group("mobile").sum("calls").as("totalCalls"),
        project("totalCalls")
    );

AggregationResults<Doc> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "yoCollection", Doc.class);
Doc doc = results.getMappedResults().get(0);
```

Comment: After reformatting long chained methods, it's working! Thanks, maybe missing closing parenthesis was the problem, but I wonder why eclipse didn't warn me :)